# Read label using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Can anyone help me to read a label text from selenium webdriver

The for attribute value and label text are entirely different

Comment: Please provide the HTML code so that it is easier to answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the label looks in HTML something like this:

```
<span id="spannyspan" title="the Title of SPAN">The Text</span>
```

then the WebElement will be best approached like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement theSpan = driver.findElement(By.id("spannyspan"));
String title = theSpan.getAttribute("title");
String label = theSpan.getText();
System.out.println(title); // will return "the Title of SPAN"
System.out.println(label); // will return "The Text"
// both without apostrophes ofcourse
```

If this does not help please provide sample HTML of label which you are trying to fetch

Comment: As I don't know- is it the best way to make a WebElement for non functional HTML Elements as a label?

Comment: In case you need get text from span, then yes. Imagine that the span will hold the Order ID which can be later on verified against database...

Comment: I just thought there could be a something like a passive WebElement with reduced instructionset

Comment: If there is, I am not aware of it

Comment: @PavelJanicek: Good example with providing HTML code by your own. According to you it would work fine, I think. But, It was better if the poster could provide the snippet of HTML code.

Comment: Yes. But this is not perfect world ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a label contain text "hello":

```
    <label>hello</label>
```

then what you have to do is:
    # first find this element using xpath or css locator and store that into WebElement object:

```
    WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'hello')]");
```

# After that using `getText()` method you can get the text of the label `element.getText()` method return value in string so,store the value in the string variable

```
String lbltext =  label.getText();
```

# After that if you want to print the value then

```
    System.out.println("text = "+lbltext);
```

Comment: Please consider reformatting your answer. It's quite hard to read with these monster bold texts and unformatted code snippets. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).